# Foundation 5: Undefined variable: "$rem-base"

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

I just installed `Foundation 5` and created a new project with compass:

```
$ foundation new myproject && cd myproject && foundation update
```

In order to modify my column's gutter, I commented out `@import "foundation/functions";` and `$column-gutter` in my `_settings.scss`:

```
// Uncomment to use rem-calc() in your settings
@import "foundation/functions";

...

$column-gutter: rem-calc(30);
```

But `Compass` says:

```
error scss/app.scss (Line 49 of scss/_settings.scss: Undefined variable: "$rem-base".
```

I also tried creating a project with `libsass`:

```
$ foundation new myproject --libsass && cd myproject && foundation update
```

However `grunt` says:

```
Warning: bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/functions:49: error: unbound variable $rem-base
```

What else should I do?

Comment: Have you tried setting a `$rem-base` variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you download sass files from github this problem solved 4 days ago by adding `$rem-base: 16px !default;` to _functions.scss file:
https://github.com/zurb/foundation/commit/3a48ef984309023b5b8c9c67fb4134a998728773

You have two solution:

- Downlaod latest version of zurb-foundation from github: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/
- Add `$rem-base: 16px !default;` to `_settings.scss` file before `@import "foundation/functions"`

Comment: Line 22 of settings.scss has this commented out. Just un-comment it. 
//$rem-base: 16px;